Can a stationary intermediary relay communications that would otherwise be impossible?
Station Omega is a galactic transit hub for crewed spacecraft traveling at high subliminal speeds.  Say 0.8C or thereabouts.  The station can be considered "stationary" relative to any spacecraft departing it.
Two spacecraft, Ship A and Ship B depart Station Omega at the same time and in opposite directions.  Direct communication between them using any conventional means should be impossible, on the basis that the distance between them is increasing at a rate of 1.6C, so a broadcast from one ship can't ever reach the other (I believe?).
The question is, can Station Omega circumvent this and act as a communications relay between the two ships (albeit with a frustratingly long round-trip time)?  From the station's perspective both ships are observable and can be communicated with, as each one is "only" traveling at 0.8C; so comms possible, but it takes awhile.  It can receive a message from Ship A, and then transmit a copy of that message to Ship B.  If everyone is patient enough (and has enough credits to make it worth Station Omega's time), Ship B can even send a reply back to the station, and then onwards to Ship A.  This seems like it's possible without any special or counterintuitive physics?
However if that's the case, it begs a further question of why Station Omega is needed as a relay in the first place, doesn't it?  Station Omega can't emit photons that travel towards Ship B any faster than the ones that Ship A emits do; they're just not as red-shifted (I think?).  If that's the case, does something prevent Station Omega from acting as a relay?  Or conversely, is there something that allows observability and direct communication between Ship A and Ship B even though they're moving away from each other faster than their communications can travel?
I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm not sure what.

The station can be considered "stationary" relative to any spacecraft departing it? How? I can be stationary to a train leaving a station only if I am either running along with the train or being on the train.

This is not worldbuilding, this is simply a matter of applying the equations for special relativity and belongs on Physics SE.  In brief - ship A and ship B cannot travel away from each other at 1.6 c no matter how long or hard they accelerate.  There is no "privileged" frame of reference in relativity, so you can't treat Station Omega as such.

@LDutch I guess I phrased that poorly.  I mean the station experiences no meaningful motion of its own for the purposes of the example.  A spacecraft that departs "upwards" at 0.8C is always moving upwards at 0.8C as far as any observer on the station can tell.  Ditto for one moving "downwards".  As in, the station isn't moving around under its own power, isn't subject to any relevant orbital anomalies (not whizzing around a black hole at ludicrous speeds), and so on.

@KerrAvon2055 - "In brief - ship A and ship B cannot travel away from each other at 1.6 c no matter how long or hard they accelerate" - That doesn't make sense though.  If one object can leave a point in space at a particular heading and speed, another can leave the same point at the same speed on an opposite heading.  For any speed over 0.5C the distance between them increases at a rate greater than 1C.  Linguistically at least it seems valid to describe this as moving away from each other at a speed above 1C.

aroth - please ask on Physics SE, it is inappropriate for me to answer in comments.  Newtonian physics is what 99.9% of people find intuitive and is what your assumptions are based on, but you need to understand special relativity when looking at travel at large fractions of c.  It doesn't matter how long a ship boosts away at, for example, 1G, it can never attain light speed with respect to its point of departure.  The same applies if a ship is (effectively) boosting away at 2G from another ship - they can still never attain light speed with respect to each other.

@KerrAvon2055 this is hardly even a physics question, it's very basic algebra. To make it simpler you can imagine that the question is about two people walking away from each other at 4 km/h and a third running between them at 5 km/h, the math works out the same.

@user111403 and when I had a quick look at PhysicsSE for existing answers, I'm finding a "do my homework" question posted 2 hours ago that was closed 1 hour ago involving a spaceship travelling at 0.8 c https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/837503/special-relativity-distance-between-two-events-lorentz-transformations then this question was asked here 10 minutes later

Effectively a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11398/almost-double-light-speed - I've VTC'd that it's not worldbuilding though since dups on other sites don't count.

@OP your mistake is assuming that the message is somehow "dragged along" by the first ship and that it needs to compensate for its speed, but it doesn't, it's sent from a fixed point and travels from there at c. Spaceship B is moving away from Spaceship A at 1.6c, but it's moving away from the point the message was sent at only 0.8c. You could say that the message and Spaceship A are travelling in opposite directions at a relative speed of 1.8c. Eventually the message can get to B and return, you don't need the intermediate station.

@user111403 Thank you, that (second post) makes enough sense.  The first not quite, because there's no fundamental rule against going faster than 5 kph.  And thanks to
KerrAvon2055 for reminding me why I've largely avoided SE sites for the past several years.  People thinking they know better than OP's where their questions belong, refusing to answer questions for the same reason, etc.. Not considering that this could be an important mechanic for a world I'm building. Or that Physics.SE was rejected because 1) the Q is too basic for there, and 2) I want layman's terms, not a math lecture.

@aroth the point of the first comment is that you can replace c with literally any unit and the mathematical reasoning works the same. By introducing c into the equation you've just confused yourself and perhaps others.

The part where you ask "(I believe?) is a definite NO.  The whole deal with special relativity is that speeds don't add up like in Newtonian relativity.  The ships are moving away from one another at 0.976 c, and can communicate with each other directly or relayed via the base with exactly the same time delay for the communication.  There's nothing to really answer here, apart from basic physics discussion, so you should withdraw the question once you understand that article.

@aroth: "the distance between them increases at a rate greater than 1c": Distance is not absolute. This means that it makes no sense to speak about $\rightarrow$the$\leftarrow$ distance. There is only distance from the point of view of an observer sitting in a specific frame of reference. Yes, from the point of view of an observer sitting at the point of departure the distance between the ships grows at a rate faster than the speed of light; but that's irrelevant for any practical purpose. From the point of view of the ships themselves the distance grows at a rate slower than c.

If one ship is travelling at 0.8c away from a station in one direction, and a second ship is travelling away from m the station at 0.8c n the opposite direction, than the two ships are moving away from each other at a bit less than the speed of light, as seen from either ship. It’s counter-intuitive if you’re only used to dealing with speeds much less than light-speed, but it’s indisputably true.

The nice thing about Special Relativity is, any light (or radio signal) emitted from spacecraft A propagates at speed of light in the reference frame of spacecraft B. As a result, spacecraft A is not perceived as traveling at > c from spacecraft B: they see spacecraft A where it is no longer. Ain't cool?

@FrançoisJurain It’s not about perception. Spacecraft A really is moving away from spacecraft B at less than the speed of light.

If you want a science-based answer, then you're going to need to write a science-based question - as it stands your mathematics indicate a space-time where the laws are different from those that apply here. Could you tell us about that in detail?

@MikeScott the way I understand Relativity, we are blind, in the very proper sense of the word, to anything faster than light and every other physical system than the human eye is blind as well. So there is nothing more to reality than what we can perceive of it. So: OK about really is moving and you're welcome to accept "it's about perception" as well.

FRAME CHALLENGE: As others have noted ships A and B will (in theory) always be able to exchange signals because both are traveling below the absolute speed limit of light. Message lag however will obviously increase as the distance between the two ships grows. Where the Station might be useful however is as a relay point since the station is presumably much, much larger than the ships and can therefore house both correspondingly larger power sources and larger/more sensitive transmitter/receiver arrays.
Signals from both ships could therefore be received by the station and transmitted on-wards at much higher power levels and with a much narrower focus than the ships might be able to manage on their own as the distance between them grows longer. Your ships would therefore be able to stay in contact over far longer distances and for a far longer time than they would be if they had to rely solely their own onboard transmitters. Not forever mind you, just longer.

Let's draw a spacetime diagram!
Here's the situation described in the OP (or, uhh... one possible interpretation of it, anyway):

The horizontal axis represents space and the vertical axis represents time. Assume the height of the diagram represents one year of time, and the width of the diagram represents one light-year of distance.
The yellow lines labeled "ɣ" represent photons. Note that they are all oriented at precisely 45° on this diagram. This is because photons travel at precisely one light-year per year.
The orange line labeled "Ω" is the world line of Omega Station. It is moving at 0.8c to the right, relative to... whatever the OP had in mind when they said Omega Station was traveling at 0.8c, if that is indeed what they intended to say and not a misinterpretation on my part.
Let's call this hypothetical object "The Galactic Core". Its world line is the vertical black line, labeled "GC".
Omega Station passes through the Galactic Core at the bottom left corner of the diagram. A month or two later, Ship A and Ship B (represented by the blue and green "A" and "B" lines, respectively) depart from Omega Station in opposite directions, each traveling at 0.8c relative to the station.
This puts Ship A at rest relative to the Galactic Core; hence, Ship A's worldline is vertical. Ship B is moving in the same direction as Omega Station, so its speed is closer to that of light, and the slope of its worldline is closer to the 45° photon lines. I can't be bothered to do the math to calculate Ship B's precise speed, but I'd estimate it to be about 0.95-0.99c. I'm sure calculators for this sort of thing exist online.
The three photon lines shown in this diagram represent:

A message sent from Omega Station out ahead of Ship B at the same time as the ships' departure
A message sent from Ship B roughly four months after the ships' departure (by Ship A's reckoning), which Ship A received four months later
A message sent from Ship A very shortly after departure, received by Ship B roughly eight months later (by Ship A's reckoning).

I interpret this line from the OP

The station can be considered "stationary" relative to any spacecraft departing it.

to mean

We can consider a frame of reference in which Omega Station is stationary, and we can think about the ships' movements in this frame of reference.

which is true.
To demonstrate this, we can perform a Lorentz transform to shift our perspective into Omega Station's frame of reference. This amounts to squishing the diagram from top-right to bottom-left and stretching it from top-left to bottom-right, ensuring that the photon lines remain at 45°, until Omega Station's world line is vertical. Like this:

Now we can see Ship A and the Galactic Core moving to the left at 0.8c and Ship B moving to the right at 0.8c, while Omega Station remains stationary in the middle with a vertical world line.
I was not careful about the scale of the diagram when I transformed it, so it no longer covers one year of time or one light-year of space. Nonetheless, we can make the following observations:

Omega Station's initial message remains ahead of Ship B
Ship A's message passes Omega Station long before Ship B's message does
Ship B receives Ship A's message long before Ship A receives Ship B's message according to Omega Station's reckoning. (Aside: Recall that, by Ship A's reckoning, both messages arrived at the same time. This discrepancy is called "relativity of simultaneity".)

Also note that, since both ships are moving at the same speed in this reference frame, they have the same so-called "gamma factor" and they experience the same amount of time dilation. Which means that the last observation above also applies to the ships' internal clocks (their "proper time"). While Ship A's clocks show that Ship B's message arrived roughly eight months after departure, Ship B's clocks will show that Ship A arrived after much less time than that. Less than a month, I'd estimate; perhaps only a matter of days.
We can perform the same Lorentz transform again to shift into Ship B's frame of reference:

Ship B's worldline is now vertical, and everything else (except the photon messages) is moving to the left at a large fraction of lightspeed. It's hard to see what's going on with Ship A and Omega Station in this view, not least of all because most of the action is cut off by the edges of the diagram.
However, we can see that both messages were sent at about the same time by Ship B's reckoning. That is to say, once Ship A's message arrives, Ship B's crew will be able to calculate when Ship A must have sent it, given Ship A's trajectory and the lightspeed delay, and they'll discover that Ship A must have sent their message at almost exactly the same time that Ship B sent theirs. Of course, it'll take quite a while longer for Ship B's message to catch up to Ship A.
... That's all a very long-winded way to say that the ships can beam messages at each other, and the messages will arrive eventually, even if the ships are moving away from each other at well over 0.5c. However, as other answers note, there may still be some value in having Omega Station act as a signal relay, boosting and un-redshifting signals that might otherwise become too faint for the receiving ship to pick up.
But I hope the diagrams can provide some insight into some of the more counterintuitive consequences of special relativity. They're certainly a very powerful tool.

Too late now, but I wish the lines labeled "ɣ" had different labels, ɣ1, ɣ2, and ɣ3. It would make it easier to tell them apart.

I like the idea of a station traveling relativistically
It has problems, such as moving considerably faster than any solar system, and it would be orbiting the center of a galactic core... but the idea is uber cool.
But there are a few things you need to realize from a science perspective.
Light moves at 1.0c. Period.
Physicists, please correct me if I'm wrong! (I'll delete this if I'm really wrong... I'm an engineer, not a physicist.)
Light moves at 1.0c. If your station is moving north at 0.8c and you emit a beam of light southward, it won't be traveling at 0.2c. It will be traveling at 1.0c. The reason this doesn't seem to make sense is that at relativistic speeds, the perspective of the observation becomes very important. From the perspective of the emitted photon, it's moving at 1.0c. From the perspective of someone on, say, Earth, the photon is moving at 1.0c and the station is moving at 0.8c. I'm not sure what would be seen from the perspective of the station, but I know it doesn't matter.
Unless you have FTL travel/communication in your universe, no information can travel faster than 1.0c because light is the only medium you have to work with to get the fastest transit. From that perspective, a ship moving south at 0.8c emitting a beam of light traveling 1.0c toward the station moving north at 0.8c will eventually reach it because the light is moving north at 1.0c and the station is moving north at 0.8c. The fact that the ship is moving south at 0.8c doesn't matter.
So, yes, your ship moving south can communicate with the station/ship despite the distance between them increasing at a rate of 1.6c. The solution works because light moves at one speed regardless of the direction it's emitted or the velocity/direction of the object from which it's emitted.
It's important that the rate of increasing distance DOES NOT represent a velocity. It's merely a rate-of-change. Nothing is traveling faster than the speed of light. From the perspective of the photon, the object that emitted it wasn't moving at all.
By definition, the ship traveling south can communicate with the ship traveling north for the same reason. However, that brings up an issue.
Can a ship traveling north actually leave the station?
It doesn't matter if we're talking about space stations moving at 0.8c or an ocean liner moving at 30 knots. If the approaching ship cannot exceed that speed, we have some problems.

A ship directly south of our northbound space station can never catch up to the space station.

That means a ship must be ahead of the station or, in the course of its travel, cross the path of the space station at a point ahead of the station. This is little different than leading a moving target with a rifle. You need to approach where the station will be when you get there. It's tempting to suggest that a tangentially moving space ship could approach the station at exactly the right moment to sidle up to the station, but that's a high risk maneuver because if you miss the station, you can't catch up to it. It's more realistic to move into line ahead of the station, then slow down to allow the station to catch up.

But that also means that a ship traveling along the same vector as the station shouldn't bother separating from the station. It can move laterally away from the station, but it can't move past it along the station's vector. Of course, the station is (I believe) orbiting a galactic core so other than temporarily, no ship would be moving exactly along the same vector. They'd be veering off to their destination.


What all that means is...

The closer an approaching ship is to the opposite vector of the station, the less useful the station is to the ship.

The closer a departing ship must be to the same vector as the station, the less valuable it is to bother leaving.


The messy case of a ship traveling in the opposite direction
For a ship traveling in the opposite direction of the station to successfully stop at the station, it must first decelerate to 0.0c, then re-accelerate to 0.8c in the same direction as the station. Yes, you could think of the ship doing that as traveling in a long curve which would result in it sidling up to the station. But when you analyze the physics, that's basically the same thing. In relation to the station, the ship had to come to a stop, then re-accelerate.
Why do many police cars traveling on a northbound road not bother to turn around and catch a speeder on a southbound road? Because unless the police car is very fast and the speeder comparatively slow, the time it takes to come to a relative stop and re-accelerate can make the offending vehicle too much work to catch. Don't get me wrong, I've seen them do it, but more often, I've seen them not. Besides, it's easier to radio to a compatriot anyway.
A ship docked at the station wanting to travel in the opposite direction has the same problem. It must slow to 0.0c then re-accelerate to 0.8c.
From a "realistic" perspective, nobody would do that. The energy cost would make the value of stopping at the station too low. It would make more sense to have a second station moving in the opposite direction.
Finally: An argument for the space station moving just a bit slower
After saying all that, I hope you'll agree that it would make sense for the station to move at, say, 0.79c when all the ships can move at 0.8c. It allows ships to catch up and would make the process of docking a whole lot more forgiving.
A physicist might argue that there's a huge difference between 0.79c and 0.8c and that the energy required to catch up/slow down even by 0.01c is a big deal. I'd agree, but this is worldbuilding.se, not physics.se, and the goal is suspension of disbelief, not scientific veracity. Cheers.

Physicist speaking: your thoughts on $c$ being constant across reference frames are correct :)

The docked ship that wants to go in the other direction will move in an elliptic trajectory, first moving away from the station and then slingshot around other celestial objects to go the way they want to. It wouldn't just "stop and turn".

@MindwinRememberMonica If you read my answer more closely, I mention the long curve (aka "elliptic trajectory") and note that the "stop and turn" is in relation to the station. Further, I also pointed out that ships flying with the station would simply remain docked and that in likely every case they would veer away from the station. Did you actually read the answer?

Oh, you mean it would appear to have a retrograde orbit/trajectory from the station's referential... right.

As others have pointed out, velocities don't add that way. A signal transmitted from each ship will always reach the other eventually. However, it will be redshifted and time dilated, potentially beyond the other ship's ability to clearly receive it. The shift in the frame of the station will be lower, so it could still be able to receive the transmission and retransmit it so the other ship could receive it.
Additionally, there is the simple matter of distance. Communications ranges will be limited regardless of relative velocity. The range can be extended with larger receivers or more powerful transmitters: a fixed station isn't as limited in either respect as a mobile ship, and can relay a weak signal at higher power.
A third factor: it's not practical to broadcast signals at interstellar distances, you'd be trying to outshout stars. Realistically, your transmissions will be tightly focused at their recipients. This requires knowledge of where exactly they are and will be. The further you are, the more out of date this knowledge will be. However, the station doesn't maneuver: everyone always knows where it is and can keep it up to date with their flight plans. If there's multiple stations, each ship only has to keep in contact with the nearest one, and they can pass messages between them to ships beyond communications range.
